# Using xpath string functions with list of results

Tags: dom, xpath

I got his piece of html

```
<select name="super_attribute[517]" id="attribute517" class="required-entry super-attribute-select validation-failed">
    <option value="">Choose an Option...</option>
    <option value="840">34: $159.95</option>
    <option value="839">34.5: $159.95</option>
    <option value="841">35: $159.95</option>
    <option value="842">35.5: $159.95</option>
</select>
```

I want to get a list of values with xpath {34, 34.5, 35, 35.5}, but it looks like i cant process lists of values with string functions like string-before.

```
substring-before(//select[@id='attribute517']/option[position()>1]/text(), ":")
```

This xpath returns `34`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have access to XPath 2.0 or 3.0 or XQuery 1.0 or 3.0 where you can indeed generate a sequence of values doing

```
//select[@id='attribute517']/option[position()>1]/substring-before(., ':')
```

you can't do it in pure XPath alone.

So with XPath 1.0 you need to iterate over the result of `//select[@id='attribute517']/option[position()>1]` and then apply the expression `substring-before(., ':')` on each node you iterate over.